# I'm getting an error of "icons[0].addClass("change") is not a function". How could I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

```
const icons = $(".section-1-icons i")

let i = 1

setInterval(()=>{
    i=i+1

    const icon = $(".section-1-icons change").removeClass("change")
    if (i>icons.length){
        icons[0].addClass("change")
        i = 1
    }else {
        icon.next().addClass("change")
    }

},2000)
```

Comment: Change `[0]` to `.first()` or `.eq(0)`. Array indexing returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery returns a special object of results, not an array. So, doing `icons[0]` gets the underlying DOM element, not the jQuery object for that element. You want to use `icons.eq(0)` instead. Like this:

```
const icons = $(".section-1-icons i");
let i = 1;
setInterval(() => {
    i = i + 1;
    const icon = $(".section-1-icons change").removeClass("change")
    if (i > icons.length){
        icons.eq(0).addClass("change");
        i = 1
    } else {
        icon.next().addClass("change");
    }
}, 2000);
```